# ExtJS - How to create a hello world application in Adobe AIR

Tags: javascript, air, extjs

Folks,

I am new to `ExtJS`. I know a bit of Adobe AIR programming.
I wanted to start programming in `ExtJS` for `Adobe AIR`.

Can anyone please help me getting started with `ExtJS + Adobe AIR` with a simple Hello World example.?

Thanks

---

**Edit :** I saw Jack Slocum's blog regarding this, but his code is too complicated to get started. So, an Hello World example would serve better start.